# How do I set a variable in Foundry's SQL Transforms?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

Is there a way to set variables in Foundry's transforms-sql? I have a list of values that I reference multiple times in a query that would ideally just specify once.

Currently doing:  `SELECT * FROM foo WHERE param IN ('a', 'b', 'c')`

Want to do something like: `SET param_list = ('a', 'b', 'c') SELECT * FROM foo WHERE param IN @param_list`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, SparkSQL as a language doesn't support variables yet, so your best alternative would be to rewrite this transform in Python. It will support dynamic queries, parameters, and all manner of more expressive queries.